# Sort comments by karma

Tags: comments, sort

I'm using the plugin [comments rating](http://wealthynetizen.com/comment-rating-pro/) (thumbs up - thumbs down) on my comments template. 
It stores "karma" in the db column "comment_karma" in comments table. 
I am looking for a way to sort wp_list_comments by higher karma to lowest.

Have tried something like

```
<?php wp_list_comments('callback=mu_custom_callback&orderby=comment_karma&order=DESC') ?>
```

but it's not working.

thanks

**UPDATE**

I got it working placing in functions.php `

```
function comment_comparator($a, $b)
    {
        $compared = 0;
        if($a->comment_karma != $b->comment_karma)
        {
            $compared = $a->comment_karma < $b->comment_karma ? 1:-1;
        }
        return $compared;
        }
```

and in comments.php

```
global $wp_query;
    $comment_arr = $wp_query->comments;
    usort($comment_arr, 'comment_comparator');
    wp_list_comments('callback=gtcn_basic_callback', $comment_arr);
```

Found on this [website](http://www.theunusableweb.com/tips/coding/php-coding/wordpress/re-order-wordpress-comments/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just incase if you have not checked out the [**plugin developers page**](http://wealthynetizen.com/comment-rating-pro/) but heres something that you could try

```
if (function_exists(ckrating_get_comments)) {
$post_id = $post->ID;
$mycomments = ckrating_get_comments(
"post_id=$post_id&status=approve&
orderby=comment_karma&order=DESC");
}
else
$mycomments = null;
wp_list_comments(array(), $mycomments);
```

**UPDATE**

I got it working placing in functions.php
I got it working placing in functions.php `function comment_comparator($a, $b)

```
function comment_comparator($a, $b)
    {
        $compared = 0;
        if($a->comment_karma != $b->comment_karma)
        {
            $compared = $a->comment_karma < $b->comment_karma ? 1:-1;
        }
        return $compared;
        }
```

and in comments.php

```
global $wp_query;
    $comment_arr = $wp_query->comments;
    usort($comment_arr, 'comment_comparator');
    wp_list_comments('callback=gtcn_basic_callback', $comment_arr);
```

Found on this [website](http://www.theunusableweb.com/tips/coding/php-coding/wordpress/re-order-wordpress-comments/)

Comment: Thanks Martin. Of course I have tried that before, result: the voting buttons are disappearing and ordering is not by karma but the default. If I try that without custom callback, comment section is not displayed anymore. Maybe I am putting it in the wrong place (i am pasting it in comments.php replacing the actual wp_list_comments )

Comment: sorry I edited your reply instead of my question.

Answer (score 0):

@ Andycap Thats exactly what i am looking for. but somehow it doesn't work for me. I am pretty shure that i am doing something wrong. Can you explain where exactly to put the code in the functions.php and the comments.php. do i have to add your code or replace it?

Comment: exactly as I wrote, first code goes in functions.php (wherever you want, it's a function), second part goes in comments.php where you call wp_list_comments and call your callback function (of course you have to change callback=gtcn_basic_callback to your callback name). You can find more details on the link I provided in my question.

Comment: wow, what a fast answer, thanks alot!! i already checked out the link you posted and didn't understand what to do, but with your response i think i know what to do now. so, thanks alot again!

Comment: just put the code as described and it worked like charm. thanks a alot andycap, you made a chubby pale german as happy as a chubby german can be!!

Comment: glad to help you! just please upvote my question for some good karma!